# Wordpress(wp_signon) taking me as not logged in user

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two portals one is jsp and another one is wordpress, I am trying to make common login for both portals(i.e when a user is logged in from jsp at the same time he need to log-in wordpress also   ). So i write the bellow code

```html
$creds['user_login'] =$userid[0];
    $creds['user_password'] = $user_password;
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
       // print_r($user);
    if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
        echo $user->get_error_message();
}else{
//echo $user->ID.'dd';
get_currentuserinfo($user->ID);
$user_id = $user->ID;
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id ); 
if( $user ) {
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login );
}
global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      //echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
```

With the above code i can able to get logged in user details ...But when i try to go to admin it is asking for log-in credentials

Comment: Are you passing admin login details in $userid?

Comment: it is for users...so iam passing user details

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your setup for both sites, but have you tried to change the cookie constants in the wordpress site ?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Set_Cookie_Domain
http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Additional_Defined_Constants